# Do I need to append dispatch_uid to signal in this case?

Tags: django

On Django Documentation, I read this : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals

> In some circumstances, the code connecting receivers to signals may
>   run multiple times. This can cause your receiver function to be
>   registered more than once, and thus called multiple times for a single
>   signal event.

Then, If I use signal as,

```
class CustomauthConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'

    def ready(self):
        import myapp.signals
```

And

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=TestModel)
def update_log(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    TestModelLog.objects.create(description=instance.description, datetime=instance.updated)
```

**Question:**

Is it right that I don't need `dispatch_uid`?

Or if I have to use `dispatch_uid`, Would you give me a sample for using `dispatch_uid`?

My purpose is to prevent duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the signal to `create` a new Log (although your function is named `update_log`) you are probably better off using [`update_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update_or_create) method:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=TestModel)
def update_log(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    TestModelLog.objects.update_or_create(
        description=instance.description, datetime=instance.updated
    )
```